# Paging a Repeater that uses SQLDataReader as Source

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, repeater, sqldatareader

How should I go about paging  a Repeater that is using a SQLDataReader to input the data? I was thinking about using this J[Query Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/paginateTable)? Should I use something else, I have tried to do some research but I found information on SQLDataAdapters but repeaters werent as clear. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the DataPager control ([MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datapager.aspx))

This control does not work with a Repeater but you can use it with a ListView control.  The ListView control works like a super-charged repeater.  Since the ListView implements the  IPageableItemContainer interface, you will be able to page through results.

Take a look here for a detailed example: [Data Navigation with the ListView, DataPager and SliderExtender Controls](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/12/data_navigation_with_the_listv.html)